# Python Scraping URL issue

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a simple python3 script to extract as many public repositories as i can from Sourceforge.net.  I ran into a weird issue with the url that I am curious as to why its happening:

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = []

for i in range(1,100):
    cur = 'http://sourceforge.net/directory/os%3Alinux/freshness%3Arecently-updated/?page=' + str(i)
    #print(cur + '\n')
    r = get(cur.format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    results += soup.find_all('span',{'itemprop': 'name'})
    for result in results:
        print('Found Project: '.join(result.contents))
    time.sleep(.5)
    results = []
```

The issue arises when I remove the /os%3Alinux/ from the url in order to have a broader range of projects... when I do this, the output is the output for page 1 over and over again.  Does not extract the other pages it seems.  Does anyone know as to why this is happening?  Also I got the r = get(cur.format(i)) from somebody else and am curious as to what this is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://sourceforge.net/directory/freshness%3Arecently-updated/?page=1
```

is not a valid URL. It redirects to:

```
http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/
```

So when you increment your counter, you are always redirecting back to the same URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



for page in range(1, 100):
   r  = requests.get("http://sourceforge.net/directory/?page=" + str(page))
   data = r.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

   print soup.find_all('span',{'itemprop': 'name'})
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the os:windows/os:linux tag? without causing the issue?  If not I can just run both OSes and remove common ones.  But thanks for the answer nontheless

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/directory/freshness%3Arecently-updated/?page=1 covers all OSes.

Comment: unfortunately the issue i run into when I change to this url is that it does not produce any results other than the first page

Comment: Are you still incrementing your counter for each page?

Comment: @codyjae I added code to print the html of every page, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes, I don't know if it has to do with my operating system or not.  It works only if I have an OS selected and something in the freshness:recently-updated section.  Without both of those it just repeats the same page, but this doesn't happen when I use that url with my browser.  Not a huge deal, I'm just trying to better understand it